# Audio output and Audio input flag denied by client on implementing pjsua2 voice call on Android 5.1?

Tags: android, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I am implementing pjsua2 sample app for voice call on Android devices. It works well on android version 8, 9, 10, 11 without issue. But when I tested on Android 5.1, I can receive call from sip soft phone without any issue. But outgoing call only rings on the other side without any voice.

From the log its mentioned that both `AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST` as well as `AUDIO_INPUT_FLAG_FAST` denied by client. can any one suggest me how to rectify this issue.

as per below log : audio details

> minFrameCount: 1857, afFrameCount=1024, minBufCount=5, sampleRate=16000, afSampleRate=44100, afLatency=115

```
 4-12 16:17:42.320 4922-4922/org.pjsip.pjsua2 I/System.out: 16:17:42.320   pjsua_call.c !Making call with acc #0 to sip:syz@sip.xcd.com
04-12 16:17:42.321 4922-4922/org.pjsip.pjsua2 I/System.out: 16:17:42.320    pjsua_aud.c  .Set sound device: capture=-1, playback=-2
04-12 16:17:42.321 4922-4922/org.pjsip.pjsua2 I/System.out: 16:17:42.321    pjsua_aud.c  ..Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
04-12 16:17:42.321 4922-4922/org.pjsip.pjsua2 I/System.out: 16:17:42.321   opensl_dev.c  ...Creating OpenSL stream
04-12 16:17:42.322 4922-4922/org.pjsip.pjsua2 W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
04-12 16:17:42.322 4922-4922/org.pjsip.pjsua2 I/AudioTrack: minFrameCount: 1857, afFrameCount=1024, minBufCount=5, sampleRate=16000, afSampleRate=44100, afLatency=115
04-12 16:17:42.323 4922-4922/org.pjsip.pjsua2 W/AudioRecord: AUDIO_INPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
04-12 16:17:42.336 4922-4922/org.pjsip.pjsua2 I/System.out: 16:17:42.335   ec0xb8b41d98  ...Speex AEC created, clock_rate=16000, channel=1, samples per frame=320, tail length=200 ms, latency=0 ms
04-12 16:17:42.336 4922-4922/org.pjsip.pjsua2 I/System.out: 16:17:42.336   opensl_dev.c  ...Starting OpenSL stream..
04-12 16:17:42.347 4922-4922/org.pjsip.pjsua2 I/System.out: 16:17:42.347   opensl_dev.c  ...OpenSL stream started
```

Comment: try using PCMA codec

Comment: I am using PCMA /800 but still getting this error, further help, error specific to Android version

Comment: You might get better results if you ask on the mailing list... Ming might be of some help.

Comment: may I ask which mailing list ?

Comment: Well, there's this one `pjsip-request@lists.pjsip.org` however... i'm not sure nor remember how to apply to it (them, there are several). You'll have to dig it out yourself somehow.  Also, take a look at https://pjsip.pjsip.narkive.com/ - maybe your problem was already covered at some point. Finally, don't expect prompt responses, since only the people that purchased the commercial licence have a dedicated support, which doesn't go through the lists but directly with telus/pjsip developers.